# How to manage configuration in a windows 2008 R2 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, configuration-management

I'm using ec2 to host a windows server (2008 R2).

This server is strictly for serving an ASP.NET MVC website on IIS, nothing more.

Once I have things setup, I want to be able to create duplicate copies of this server (setup wise).

What options do I have?

I know with linux I can use things like puppet.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to make clones-in-all-but-name, you can do this by cloning the AMI to a new system, booting it, and running it through [sysprep](/questions/tagged/sysprep). This will turn that new AMI into a template. When it boots next it'll require minimal setup (name at minimum) and will be a brand new server configured nearly-identically to the source. This method is used when creating, for example, a farm of .NET hosting servers that all need to be at the same code-level, upon which users will install whatever .NET apps they need.

If you're looking for puppet-style boot -> install software -> configure software style processing where to make a change to the process you just modify one config file... that's nigh impossible with Windows at the moment. Puppet is busy building Windows support right now, but isn't there yet. A good synopsis of just this problem was recently posted to the ServerFault blog ([link](http://blog.serverfault.com/post/the-state-of-management-scalability-at-stack-exchange/)), which is good reading.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to create a carbon copy of your Instance, you can create an AMI from it, which can be used to start new, identical instances. Info here: http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/index.html?AMIs.html